# Using redis as MongoDB cache with auto update

Tags: typescript, mongodb, caching, redis

I'm trying to implement a redis cache mechanism for MongoDB with event triggered cache update (the cache data will be update instead of simply evicted from redis).

This means:

1. Use redis as cache for MongoDB query result where the key is query string and value is the stringify result
2. Use MongoDB watch to monitor the change of each collection
3. When receive an update event from MongoDB, an update redis cache process will be triggered

It works fine for query that involve 1 collection; but there can also be queries contain lookup operation that involve multiple collections. It would make the update process in-efficient and difficult.

Is there any algorithm or existing package that handle such requirement?

MongoDB watch model

```
  await mongo.watchModel(
    collectionName,
    collectionSchema,
    pipeline,
    async (changeDoc: mongodb.ChangeStreamUpdateDocument, changeStream: mongodb.ChangeStream) => {
      await handleUpdate(changeDoc, changeStream);
    }
  );
```

handleUpdate will check the corresponding key and update the changeDoc into redis